# dot product and direction cosines of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given two vectors $\vec p_1$ and $\vec p_2$
and $\vec v=\vec p_2 - \vec p_1$. Hence, $\vec v=(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$. Again, we let $$\hat u=\frac{\vec v}{|v|}=(a,b,c)$$ where, 
$$a=\frac{x_2-x_1}{|v|}, b=\frac{y_2-y_1}{|v|},c=\frac{z_2-z_1}{|v|}$$, in my book these are said to be  the  direction cosines of  rotation and I  can  see  that  a, b and  c are cosines of some  angle and here $\hat u$ is some unit vector along the axis of rotation.

Now, say we project the vector $\hat u$ to the $yz$ plane as so: 
[image: corrected image of axes] we obtain  the  vector $\hat u'$ with the angle $Θ$ with the z-axis. If $\hat u_x, \hat u_y, \hat u_z$ are the unit vectors along $x,y,z$ axes respectively, my book  gives a relation:

$$\cos(Θ)= \frac{\hat u'.\hat u_z}{|\hat u'|.|\hat u_z|}=\frac{c}{d}$$
where,
$$d=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$$
and,
$$\hat u_x, \hat u_y, \hat u_z$$ are the standard unit vectors.
I understand how: 
$$\cos(Θ)= \frac{\hat u'.\hat u_z}{|\hat u'|.|\hat u_z|}$$
but, I don't  understand how:
$$\frac{\hat u'.\hat u_z}{|\hat u'|.|\hat u_z|}=\frac{c}{d}$$

How did this relation get in  there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you had purple=x axis, blue=y axis and red=z axis

Now, as $\hat{u}=(a,b,c)$ you can write $\hat{u'}=(0,b,c)$ and $\hat{u_z}=(0,0,1)$ from the way you have defined them in your question. (Here b and c are the y and z components of $\hat{u}$ )

Now $|\hat{u'}|=(b^2+c^2)^{1/2}$ and $|\hat{u_z}|=1$

So $cos\theta=\frac{\hat{u'}.\hat{u_z}}{|\hat{u'}||\hat{u_z}|}=\frac{c.1}{(b^2+c^2)^{1/2}.1}=\frac{c}{d}$

Comment: I haven't define $\hat u_z$ to be (0,0,c) and isn't it supposed to be (0,0,1)? In fact, my book gives the magnitude of $\hat u_z$ as 1 , sorry I didn't define it, but I thought it was obvious with the subscript. BTW, the Red is z axis, y is cyan and magneta is x-axis.... sorry for not defining these again.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify this as well

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it. The angle did not change since even if the rays(i.e. vectors) making the angle did elongate(i.e. change in magnitude) the angle between them was the same.